# Laravel : Class 'App\Services\OvhApiHandlerClass' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm starting Laravel and i'm trying to create an external class to use like a 'Library'.

I've searched a lot and came up with this solution :

I created a folder 'Services' in 'App' and made a class file like so :

```
App/Services/OvhApiHandlerClass.php
```

This file looks like so :

```
<?

namespace App\Services;

use App\OvhBill;
use App\OvhBillDetail;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Ovh\Api;

class OvhApiHandlerClass
{
    public function ovh_get_bills(string $consumer_key, $from = null, $to = null)
    {
       // Do something
    }
}
```

So now i want to use this class inside a controller.
But i'm getting an error saying my class does not exist.
Here is my Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Services\OvhApiHandlerClass;

class OperationsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $from = new \Carbon\Carbon('first day of January 2019');

        $ovhHandler = new OvhApiHandlerClass();

        $ovhHandler->ovh_get_bills('K87u3410p89ijKLao', $from);

        return view('operations.index');
    }
}
```

I already did, of course

`composer dump-autoload`

I'm kinda lost, what am i missing?

Thank you very much for your time !

Comment: My first thought is use `<?php`, not `<?` in case short tags aren't enabled. Even if they are, `<?php` is best practice.

Comment: Oh my god, i would have never think about this... and that was the problem ! thank you very much !!

Comment: @user6304228 Read [1, 2, 12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) (among rest of points) and you'll avoid similar issues.